Specific frequency filter
I want to use an insolation monitoring system that outputs different frequencies for every state. Exactly 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 Hz but I want to use the 10 and 50Hz only.
Is it possible to build a some sort of frequency filter that lets only 10Hz and 50Hz?

two bandpass filters

In general, there are three types of filters:

low pass (everything below a cutoff frequency passes, the rest is blocked)
high pass (everything above a cutoff frequency passes, the rest is blocked)
band-pass or band-stop (everything between two frequencies passes/is blocked)

You can add multiple filters in series to combine their effects. For your example, you want to have

a band-stop filter between 10Hz and 50Hz (add some margin, 12-48 or similar might be better). This blocks 20,30, and 40 Hz.
a low pass filter with a cutoff frequency slightly above 50Hz (to cut everything above)
a high pass filter with a cutoff frequency slightly below 10Hz (to cut everything below.

The low and high pass filters are not needed if your system only ouputs the frequencies you mentioned. Alternatively, you can also use two bandpass filters.
Note that those filters are assuming sinusoidal signals. If your signals are pulses, they will consist of a combination of multiple frequencies and the filters will not work as intended. If you have pulses, you might want to think about digital filters (e.g. a simple MCU).

Yes my system outputs the frequencies in pulses

As mentioned, I would look at a digital solution then. The proposed filters don't work as pulses consist of many different fundamental sinusoidal frequencies.
My personal implementation would be a simple microcontroller (e.g. an attiny) that measures the time between pulses and then drives an output (normal GPIO) if the pulses are at the desired frequency.
